# Changing element's look and functionality based on its content while page loads (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have been trying to tackle this challenge for two days with no success. I have the following panel-box implemented using bootstrap and AngularJS (the whole thing is inside a controller)

```html
<div id="menu2a">
  <div class="panel list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"><b>Panel Title</b></div>
    <div class="panel-body" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = '#1' 
         title = "click for more information">
      <span
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>   
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="element in UnknownSizeArray">
          <i>{{$index + 1}}) {{element}}</i>
        </li>

      </ul>       
      <div style = "padding-left:40px" id="1" class = "collapse">
        <br>
        <p> More information here..</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

`UnknownSizeArray` is the content I need to display and is sent by an Angular controller to the html page.

My problems are as follows:

1. I want the `collapse` functionality to be depended on the amount of content (say  above 5 array elements, I will show the rest in the collapsible box.
2. The chevron glyphicon must go away when the collapsability goes away
3. For 3-5 elements, I want the height of the `panel-body` (the box content) to change in order to fit more data inside without the collapse function.

How do I achieve these?

I tried the `.css()` and `.attr()` functions of jQuery on my javascript file, after calling a `data-ng-init = "test()"`from the `<div class="panel-body"`... section with no success. here one example of what I tried (same idea for .css did not work either):

```js
$scope.test = function() {
  var array = $scope.UnknownSizeArray;

  if (array.length > 5) {
    $(".panel-body").attr("data-toggle","collapse");
  };
};
```

Any ideas why it didn't work or what should be the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried addclass(), removeClass() or toggleClass()? Those can do the job.

```
<div class="panel-body collapse">
     title = "click for more information">
  <span
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>         
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="element in UnknownSizeArray">
      <i>{{$index + 1}}) {{element}}</i>
    </li>

  </ul>                         
  <div style = "padding-left:40px" id="1" class="collapse">
    <br>
    <p> More information here..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Angular script // Inside of it module -->
$scope.test = function() {
var array = $scope.UnknownSizeArray;

  if (array.length > 5) {

    $(".panel-body").addClass(".collapse");

  } else {
    // maybe the array changes and you want to go trough this function again
    $(".panel-body").removeClass(".collapse");
  }
};
```

Also, be careful with spacing in your html, like in line 4. If the original code is like this (it happens) maybe that's why jQuery can't detect and modify this element. ;)

```
4   <div class="panel-body" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = '#1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you will try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/yysajyfe/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.UnknownSizeArray = [];
  $scope.limit = 5;
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $scope.UnknownSizeArray.push(i);
  }
  $scope.expandAll = function(){
   $scope.limit = $scope.UnknownSizeArray.length;
  }
   $scope.expandNext5 = function(){
   $scope.limit += 5;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div id="menu2a">
    <div class="panel list-group">
      <div class="list-group-item"><b>Panel Title</b></div>
      <div class="panel-body" data-toggle="collapse" data-target='#1' title="click for more information">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
        <ul>
          <li data-ng-repeat="element in UnknownSizeArray|limitTo:limit">
            <i>{{$index + 1}}) {{element}}</i>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <div ng-if="limit<UnknownSizeArray.length">
          <br>
          <button ng-click="expandAll()"> Expand all</button>
          <button ng-click="expandNext5()"> Expand next 5</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```